# Error jumping between viewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, loops, storyboard, viewcontroller

Having some difficultly with this one.
I am loading questions, answers, correct answers from a plist. All data is being read in fine and looks like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];   
 currentQuestion = -1;
[self showNextQuestion];
}
-(void) showNextQuestion{
        currentQuestion++;
   int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *addimage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *Answer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
   for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
    [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
    [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
    [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
    [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];
    [addimage addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"ImageUse"]];
    [Answer addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"ANS"]];
}
self.questionasked.text = question[currentQuestion];
self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];
additionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:addimage[currentQuestion]];
self.correctAns = Answer[currentQuestion];
if(currentQuestion == 4){
   [ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"levelclear" sender:nil];// here I am performing a segue to indicate that when 4 questions are displayed it will go to this view controller
}
}
```

I have 3 buttons in my VC, One for each option A,B,C which all have a function

```
- (IBAction)SelectA:(id)sender {
if ([self.correctAns isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
    currentQuestion ++;
    [self showNextQuestion];
}
else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"incorrect" sender:nil];
}
}
- (IBAction)SelectB:(id)sender {

if ([self.correctAns isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
    currentQuestion ++;
[self showNextQuestion];
}
else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"incorrect" sender:nil];

}
}
- (IBAction)SelectC:(id)sender {

if ([self.correctAns isEqualToString:@"C"]) {
    currentQuestion ++;
[self showNextQuestion];
}
else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"incorrect" sender:nil];
}
}
```

When I answer the question correctly it moves to the next question. However when I answer it incorrectly it goes to the incorrect VC informing of the incorrect question. This VC has a segue when the button is pressed to go back to the question VC(which I made in the storyboard). It does go back to the question VC but simply jumps back to the first question. I know it is something regarding the currentQuestion but not sure what.

Comment: If you want to go back to a controller with a segue, you need to use an unwind segue, otherwise, you will create a new instance of that controller.

Comment: Yes but say I was on the 3rd question, then I got it wrong, so it showed me the incorrect VC when I click the button on the incorrect VC It brings me back to the questions VC...But at the first question. Does that make sense? I want it to go back the currentquestion

Comment: All segues (other than unwind) ALWAYS create new instance of view controllers, so when you "go back", you're not going back to the same instance, you're creating a new one, so it will go back to question 1.

Comment: OKAY...so any ideas of how i would over come this problem

Comment: Yes, I told you how. Use an unwind segue. Do you not how how to one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you segue to the incorrect answer you are destroying the questions view controller, and when yo go back to it, it is re created.

Comment: I have now created the incorrect VC as a subclass of the Question VC...Would that be right?

Comment: No, its not about subclassing. Its about or pushing the incorrect VC or storing the current question var outside the questions VC

Comment: If I saved it in my main class...and the value was updated within the question VC ...wud that updated value be the one in the incorrect VC?

Comment: Does the incorrect VC has a current question? Why does it need it?

Comment: sorry @pdrcabrod can u explain that again ...i do not understand?